# Methods in Java which can change pixel values

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I am working on an animation kind of program in java and for visualization. I am using the `swing` and `awt` libraries. I looked at a dozen implementations of this and all of them use a `paint` Component method and then `repaint()` when they want to draw shapes on the JFrame.

Is there some method that I can call from any class that I want that can for example change a single pixel value?

I also want to make an array list with shapes:

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
```

And I am curious how to add things to it. 
I was thinking:

```
Rectangle rect = "something"
rectangles.add(rect);
```

But I'm not sure what something should be. 
I am relatively new to this, so feel free to express your views if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: `Is there some method that I can call from any class?` No, Swing is not thread safe.  Read all of the tutorials here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: Use ab appropriate [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  Change the state of the model and allow the controller/view to update the view. In most cases a bitmap blit is as fast (and maybe faster) than a single pixel manipulation.

Comment: If you need direct control over the painting process, then you will need to look at using a [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html), see also [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) for more details

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apparently I was ranting when I called everyone an idiot for using repaint(); here's the better way.
Say I wanted to create a rectangle or image or line or oval on the jframe,

> public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
>      public void paintingHome(){
>      //set up the jframe and stuff
>      System.out.println("This is a rectangle");
>      paintARectangle(frame.getGraphics(), 42, 256);
>      }
>      public void paintARectangle(Graphics g, int xCoord, int yCoord, int width, int height){
>      g.fillRact(xCoord, yCoord, width, height);
>      //simple as that
>      }
>      //and you can have as many as you want
>      public void paintWhatever(Graphics g, Something whatever){
>      g.doSomethingWith(whatever);
>      //that won't actually work until oracle releases version 238249.3432.4
>      }
>      //the key is using the frame.getGraphics() method
>      //repaint is unnecessary and restrictive

Comment: Better if you could post a very small but complete example program, a [mcve], one that we can test out and compare with our own example programs. This way we can learn from each other.

Comment: You should never use `getGraphics`, it's nothing more than a snapshot of what was last painted and will be cleared/lost the next time the component is painted (try resizing the window) or the component is repainted for whatever reason.  Swing uses a passive rendering approach so a "paint" can occur at any time and Swing has a well documented and prescribed method for dealing with it. Take a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some method that I can call from any class that I want that can for example change a single pixel value?

You could create a BufferedImage, which has a `setRGB(...)` method that would achieve what you wanted by drawing the image within the `paintComponent(...)` method with Graphics `drawImage(...)` method.

With regard to `Rectangle rect = "something"` -- just look up the Rectangle constructors available to you in the [Rectangle API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) and use the most appropriate one for you.

Comment: Your paintComponent is weak and limited.

Comment: @S.Roughani: Please elaborate and educate -- by what criteria do you make this statement? Also, with your code in your recent answer, what happens if you minimize your GUI and then restore it? Do the painted images persist?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As documented by Oracle and Sun, [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), `paintComponent` is the correct approach, which is highlighted in two runnable examples provided as communitu wiki

Comment: @S.Roughani The design for the solution of your problem is what's weak and limited. An appropriately implement MVC would solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's been suggested the you should use `getGraphics` over `paintComponent`, let's take a look at that for a second...

[image: Bad idea]

Opps, oh, that didn't quite work the way we'd expect!  Let's even ignore why you shouldn't paint directly to top level containers (cause that's painting under the title bar)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JButton draw = new JButton("Draw");

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(draw);
                frame.setSize(150, 150);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                draw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        drawARectangle(frame.getGraphics());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void drawARectangle(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
    }

}
```

Okay, let's have a look at `paintComponent` and `repaint`

[image: Good Idea]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private boolean drawBox;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton draw = new JButton("Draw");
            add(draw);
            draw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    drawBox = !drawBox;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(150, 150);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (drawBox) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Swing has well documented painting process, have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details and one should work within the design of the API.

Before anyone jumps down my throat and suggest you could use a `WindowListener` or `ContainerListener` or some other listener, the answer is, why?  `paintComponent` works just fine.

Swing uses a passive rendering engine, meaning that a paint might occur for any number of reasons, most of the time which you don't instantiate or know about, so unless your linked into the painting process, you won't know that it's occurred, resizing is just a really good way to demonstrate it

So can we please stop suggesting bad approaches like using `getGraphics` or using `null` layouts or `KeyListener` or `DocumentListener` for real time filtering of text components and maybe we can save a bunch of people a bunch of head aches

Comment: AGAIN, YOU CANNOT PASS VARIABLES INTO PAINTCOMPONENT() UNLESS YOU HAVE A BUNCH OF CLASS VARIABLES THAT GET SET. THIS MEANS YOU WIND UP WITH ONE LARGE AND CLUTTERED PAINTING METHOD WITH ANOTHER MESS OF CLASS VARIABLES USED TO SPECIFY HOW THE PAINT COMPONENT PAINTS. STOP PERPETUATING THAT REPAINT() IS SUITABLE FOR ALL APPLICATIONS BECAUSE MORE PEOPLE WILL GET HEADACHES NOT KNOWING ANYTHING OTHER THAN REPAINT()

Comment: So? Use an appropriate MVC implementation and/or define a delegation/proxy model which the paintComponent method can call. This is not an excuse to break how the painting API was designed to work. You don't have to do ALL paint in the paintComponent method, but it is the root from which your custom painting should be started from. Swing has a well document painting process which, if you want things to work, you should use. If you don't want to use the painting API Swing is based on you could use anBufferStrategy instead, which gives you direct control

Comment: I would say that's a demonstration of a bad design, in over 17+ of active Swing development I can't say that repaints ever been an issue or limitation to how I've built complex applications, it's how the API works

Comment: It seems to work without any severe limitations other than that resize thing. I don't see a reason not to use it, it works for my needs, and it may in other people's as well. I want other people to know about this so if they end up in the situation I was in, they don't need to be restricted. I don't think what you've worked on for 17+ years really does matter, because there may be some kid somewhere making a GUI, struggling with repaint(), who will see this post and find it of some help.

Comment: *"because there may be some kid somewhere making a GUI, struggling with repaint()"* - So instead of teaching them appropriate design skills that they can use of over a life time, you choose to demonstrate a "hack" for the short term. *"I don't think what you've worked on for 17+ years really does matter"* - So, 17+ years of commercial Swing development counts for naught in your eyes? *"I want other people to know about this so if they end up in the situation I was in, they don't need to be restricted"* - No, we should be educating them to use appropriate patterns and designs

Comment: *"It seems to work without any severe limitations other than that resize thing"* - I would say that's a significant limitation. How about minimizing and restoring the window?  How about when the window is obscured by another window and brought to the front? It all begins to unravel.

Comment: You may speak for 99% of programs, but it's the 1% that spends hours finding posts like this on stack exchange for their needs. Thanks for bringing up the resizing limitation, I wasn't previously aware of that.

Comment: Nope, I'd say I and the other Swing developers speak for 100% of the problems, but since all I have is an out-of-context problem statement and bunch of code which won't compile or run, it's impossible to provide you with any more advice other than to learn to use an appropriate MVC and/or delegation model and work within the design of the API :P